# Codec can't encode character error using Beautiful soup 4 python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I keep getting the following error in Beatiful Soup 4 and Python 3.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
 return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 33362: character maps to <undefined>
```

The actual code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc='
yelp_r = requests.get(url)
yelp_soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_r.text, 'html.parser')
print(yelp_soup.prettify())
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error message.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: web pages use `UTF-8` encoding but Windows uses own encoding and it has problem to display it. Search question about UTF-8 in console on WIndows

Comment: when i run last line of the code it shows unicodeencodeerror so how to print it correctly

Answer (score 0):

In your code add wrap the text with `encode` method

Code:

```
yelp_soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_r.text.encode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
```

Comment: It says python3 in the question, so why are you giving a python2 solution?

Comment: use the same statement that you have used right now `print(yelp_soup.prettify())`